# I want to watch a directory for changes,if new file is arrives and send a mail with the filename

Tags: bash, shell

I created a bash script to check the directory for new file changes and send the mail to recipient.
But i am getting the error.

I created a bash script,but it is throwing the below error.

script6.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
script6.sh: line 10:`done'

Just i want to know where i am wrong.
whether the total script is wrong or there any minor error.
Need help on this.

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="/somedir"
while true; do
 files=("$targetDir"/*)
sleep 1m ## wait 1 minute
files1=("$targetDir"/*)
if [[ ${#files[@]} != ${#files1[@]} ]]; then
 mailx -s "New files arrived:$files1" some@mail.com < "$files1"
fi
done
```

My tasks are as follows.
1.observe a directory for incoming files.
2.If any new file arrives check with the existing files
3.If it is a new file send a mail to recipient
I want all the above should be achieve through bash script.

Comment: If using linux, look into the utilities provided by the `inotify-tools` package.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time we can scan directory and archive the scan results. after 
that if there is update, delete, or a new file or directory is created.

We can use this benchmark archive data for comparison and then We can then determine if the contents of the current directory have been updated.

we can use the file block size or md5 depending on what you want.

Here's a simpler way to do it, and you can also update it to use other methods of monitoring.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` directoryName"
    exit 1
fi 

firstTime=0
lastFile=last.txt
recentFile=recent.txt
currentDir=$1

if [ ! -e "$lastFile" ]; then
    firstTime=1
fi    

shopt -s extglob
cd $currentDir && du -bs !($lastFile|$recentFile) > recent.txt 2> /dev/null

if [ "$firstTime" -ne 1 ]; then
    changes=$(sed '1,/@@/d' <(diff -Naur recent.txt last.txt))
    if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
        echo "Change:"
        echo "$changes" | tee $$.tmp
        echo

        filename=$(awk '/^+/||/^-/{print $2}' $$.tmp | sort -u)
        count=0
        for f in $filename; do
            echo "changed filename: $f"
            let "count+=1"
        done
        echo -e "\nA total of $count filenames were changed."
    else
        echo "The Directory has no changes.."
    fi
else
    echo "[First run] Archiving.."
fi


cp $recentFile $lastFile

rm -rf $$.tmp 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of what you can also do:

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="22"
inotifywait -q -r -m -e create "$targetDir" |
while read -r path event filename; do
  mailx -s "New files arrived: $path$filename" some@mail.com < "$path$filename"
done
```

You need inotifywait on your system though, install by installing "inotify-tools".

Answer (score 0):

You can use inotifywait which is specially made to file watcher

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="/somedir"
inotifywait -m $targetDir -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        mailx -s "Filers arrived:$files" some@mail.com < "$files"
        # do something with the file
    done
```